# OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture mapped, but shows as black

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to get my texture to show up in a basic OpenGL view (subclass of UIView), but no matter which texture I use, it shows up black. The code for my view is as follows:

```
@implementation SymGLView

typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex;

const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (void)setupLayer {
    _eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;
    _eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
}

- (void)setupContext {   
    EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2;
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:api];
    if (!_context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to set current OpenGL context");
        exit(1);
    }
}

- (void)setupRenderBuffer {
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);        
    [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];    
}

- (void)setupDepthBuffer {
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);    
}

- (void)setupFrameBuffer {    
    GLuint framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);   
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
}

- (GLuint)compileShader:(NSString*)shaderName withType:(GLenum)shaderType {

    NSString* shaderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:shaderName ofType:@"glsl"];
    NSError* error;
    NSString* shaderString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:shaderPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (!shaderString) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading shader: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        exit(1);
    }

    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader(shaderType);    

    const char * shaderStringUTF8 = [shaderString UTF8String];    
    int shaderStringLength = [shaderString length];
    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &shaderStringUTF8, &shaderStringLength);

    glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

    GLint compileSuccess;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileSuccess);
    if (compileSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages];
        NSLog(@"%@", messageString);
        exit(1);
    }

    return shaderHandle;

}

- (void)compileShaders {

    GLuint vertexShader = [self compileShader:@"SimpleVertex" withType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
    GLuint fragmentShader = [self compileShader:@"SimpleFragment" withType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

    GLuint programHandle = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(programHandle);

    GLint linkSuccess;
    glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);
    if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages];
        NSLog(@"%@", messageString);
        exit(1);
    }

    glUseProgram(programHandle);

    _positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Position");
    _colorSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "SourceColor");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_colorSlot);

    _modelViewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Modelview");

    _texCoordSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "TexCoordIn");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordSlot);
    _textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "Texture");
}

- (void)setupVBOs {

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint indexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}

- (void)render {
    glClearColor(0, 104.0/255.0, 55.0/255.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                          sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 7));    

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _floorTexture);
    glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0);    

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), 
                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);    

    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}


- (GLuint)setupTexture:(NSString *)fileName {    

    CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);

    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4, sizeof(GLubyte));

    CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4, 
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);    

    CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);

    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

    GLuint texName;
    glGenTextures(1, &texName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

    free(spriteData);   

    return texName;    
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {        
        [self setupLayer];        
        [self setupContext];    
        [self setupDepthBuffer];
        [self setupRenderBuffer];        
        [self setupFrameBuffer];     
        [self compileShaders];
        [self setupVBOs];
        [self render];        
    }
    _floorTexture = [self setupTexture:@"tile_floor.png"];
    return self;
}


@end
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 Position;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void) { 
    gl_Position = Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main(void) { 
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
```

I can create a gradient by changing the values for gl_FragColor, but I have tried several different textures and am at a loss.

Comment: If you don't use shaders, is the texture visisble? I'm trying to determine if the problem is in the texture or the displaying of the texture.

Answer (score 6):

This could be depending on the fact that your textures are not power of 2 (i.e. 512X512)

Some OpenGL drivers react in weird ways to this, some others just perform a rescaling of the textures to the nearest power of 2 size.

From OpenGL gold book you can find the below:

You can find a quite good explanation in the OpenGL Gold Book, the OpenGL ES 2.0:

> In OpenGL ES 2.0, textures can have non-power-of-two (npot)
>   dimensions. In other words, the width and height do not need to be a
>   power of two. However, OpenGL ES 2.0 does have a restriction on the
>   wrap modes that can be used if the texture dimensions are not power of
>   two. That is, for npot textures, the wrap mode can only be
>   GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE and the minifica- tion filter can only be GL_NEAREST
>   or GL_LINEAR (in other words, not mip- mapped). The extension
>   GL_OES_texture_npot relaxes these restrictions and allows wrap modes
>   of GL_REPEAT and GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT and also allows npot textures to
>   be mipmapped with the full set of minification filters.

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: This was helpful.  On iOS, texture2D() just returns black when used with NPOT-sized texture and a wrapping mode other than clamp.